# SQL query that displays the names of Athletes who have participated in more than one event

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm building a query to display the names of athletes based on the fact that they have participated in more than one event.

For this I have to use 2 tables as shown:

```
CREATE TABLE ATHLETE(
ATHLETEID CHAR(4),
ATHLETEFIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20),
ATHLETELASTNAME VARCHAR2(20),
ATHLETEDOB DATE,
REPCOUNTRY VARCHAR2(12),
COACHID CHAR(4),
CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_PK PRIMARY KEY(ATHLETEID),
CONSTRAINT ATHLETE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(COACHID) REFERENCES COACH(COACHID));

CREATE TABLE RESULTS(
EVENTID CHAR(4),
ATHLETEID CHAR(4),
RANK NUMBER(1),
CONSTRAINT RESULTS_PK PRIMARY KEY(EVENTID,ATHLETEID),
CONSTRAINT RESULTS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(EVENTID) REFERENCES EVENTSCHEDULE(EVENTID),
CONSTRAINT RESULTS_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ATHLETEID) REFERENCES ATHLETE(ATHLETEID));
```

Using the below query I am able to show the ATHLETEID's that have participated in more than one event, what I'm struggling with is to display the name of the athlete as well because it's in a different table. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use a subquery, however I'm not sure how to build it.

`SELECT A.ATHLETEID
 FROM RESULTS A 
 GROUP BY A.ATHLETEID
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShoutCase SQL aside, you'll need to join back to athlete and then group by all non-aggregated columns, like so (note I've switched your aliasing to align to the table names):

```
 SELECT a.ATHLETEID, a.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME, 
        a.ATHLETELASTNAME, COUNT(r.EVENTID) as NumEvents
 FROM RESULTS r
   INNER JOIN ATHLETE a
   ON r.ATHLETEID = a.ATHLETEID 
 GROUP BY a.ATHLETEID, a.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME, a.ATHLETELASTNAME
 HAVING COUNT(r.EVENTID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

simply Use join with count (**Subquery Not Needed**)

```
SELECT A.ATHLETEID,ATH.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME FROM RESULTS A 
JOIN ATHLETE ATH
ON ATH.ATHLETEID =A.ATHLETEID
GROUP BY A.ATHLETEID,ATH.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Won't work in SQL Server: "Column 'ATHLETE.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME'  is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' (Or something close: checked on a different database).

Answer (score 1):

If names are unique you could group by the name as well, but in general that won't be true, so a sub-query is easy:

```
select A.ATHLETEID, a.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME, ATHLETELASTNAME 
from ATHLETE a 
where 1 < (select count(1) from RESULTS r where r.ATHLETEID = a.ATHLETEID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example for a subquery would be:

```
select A.ATHLETEID, a.ATHLETEFIRSTNAME, a.ATHLETELASTNAME 
from ATHLETE a 
where A.ATHLETEID in (SELECT R.ATHLETEID FROM RESULTS R GROUP BY R.ATHLETEID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```